# Calculate tax for cash on delivery fees in the checkoutprocess Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have two payment methods, cash on delivery and visa card. I added 10.00 SAR as cash on delivery fees. When switching it works fine. But tax is not calculating for this cash on delivery fees. How can I calculate tax for this 10 and add to subtotal and tax amount.
[image]

Here I want to add .5 in VAT and sub total and also it shows in the invoice.

## Magento 2

Comment: You can Try this Plugin for CashOnDeliveryFee ....https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee

Comment: Same plugin I used. Issue is its not calculating tax